# How can I deploy a gradle project as a EAR in Netbeans (8.1)

Tags: gradle, netbeans, netbeans-8, ear, application-server

In Netbeans 8 I have three Gradle projects:

- MyEAR

  - MyEJB
  - MyWAR

All three projects I have created inside NetBeans with "New Project...". For the EAR project I have choose "Gradle Root Project". For the other both I have select "Gradle Subproject".

But the problem is that NetBeans don't shows me the EAR project as an EAR project (it's only a gradle project). Same for the WAR and EJB project. And so I cannot deploy the EAR project because with right mouse click on the project I have no option "Deploy".

So my question: How can I deploy a gradle project as an EAR inside of NetBeans? Must I convert the project to another project? Or must I specify a additional project facet? How can I do it? Or is there a way to create at first an EAR project and convert it later to a gradle project?

Comment: I think you just need to add the `ear` plugin for gradle to give you that task...